# Perl - get specific Info from URL

Tags: perl, url, html-parsing

I'm new to Perl and having a hard time understanding how to get a specific value from a search result. Like for example, I'd like to know the number of results in a uniprot search for `swiss-prot` and `trembl`. My code goes like this:

```
#use strict
#use warnings
use LWP::Simple;

print "organism name: ";
my $SPCount = <STDIN>;
chomp($SPCount);
$SPCount =~ s/ /%20/;
$url = 'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query='.$SPCount.'&sort=score';
my $quelltext = get( $url );
```

Let's say I look for 'homo sapiens', I will get 26,138 swissprot and 919,192 TReMBL results. Should I just parse the HTML document for these numbers? How does that work?

Comment: Commenting out `use strict` and `use warnings` is a very bad idea. They are there for a reason. Take notice of what they tell you.

Comment: that's true, I thought I had that changed already

Answer (score 4):

You have to parse the returned HTML using one of the parsers on CPAN. My first choice would be [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath), which is a subclass of [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder) that allows the resultant data structure to be addressed using XPath expressions.

Looking at the HTML source of the page in question, it looks like you want the contents of the two `<a>` elements that have `id` attributes `reviewed-filter` and `unreviewed-filter`. This program demonstrates how to do that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

STDOUT->autoflush;

my $organism = <> // 'homo sapiens';
chomp $organism;
$organism =~ s/ /%20/g;

my $url = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=$organism&sort=score";

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( get( $url ) );

say "Organism Name: $organism";
say '  ', join ' ', $tree->findnodes_as_strings('//a[@id="reviewed-filter"]/node()');
say '  ', join ' ', $tree->findnodes_as_strings('//a[@id="unreviewed-filter"]/node()');
```

**output**

```
Organism Name: homo%20sapiens
  Reviewed (26,138) Swiss-Prot
  Unreviewed (919,192) TrEMBL
```